# How many processes can be run simultaneously which called by java Runtime.exec()?

Tags: parallel-processing

I just create 1000 thread and each thread call Runtime.exec() to start a process.
But when i watching parallel run process by

```
watch -n 1 'ps -ef|grep "AppName"'
```

I only found 4 processes run simultaneously at the most.
Most time it only run 2 or 1 process.

Does Runtime.exce() has a limit on process run parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only get parallelism when you have many processors or different operations going on (e.g. a slow I/O process that is run in a separate thread while the main thread continues).

If you have more threads than cores, all running the same process, all you get is time slicing as the operating system gives each thread some time.

Comment: You mean only different process name can be run parallel,the same process name can be run one per core? So how CHROME implement so many processes that exceeds core ?

Comment: Different processes, doing different things.  Time slicing is happening: the operating system will swap out threads to give everyone a turn.